# Pagespeed rewrite css, js and convert image not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos, plesk, pagespeed

I am using Mod_pagespeed on centos 7 plesk server where I host two websites with distinct ssl certificates.

Pagespeed filters such as collapse_whitespace, remove_comments work fine. However it does not rewrite and combine css, js and images.

In debug mode, I keep getting "deadline exceeded" error for all these assets.

What could be the cause?

**UPDATE:**
I managed to remove deadline exceeded error but still cannot combine css and js, and process images. Below is my current pagespeed.conf:

```
ModPagespeed On
ModPagespeedEnableCachePurge on
ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable
ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html 
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls,remove_comments,collapse_whitespace,debug
ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"
ModPagespeedLogDir "/var/log/pagespeed"

ModPagespeedRewriteDeadlinePerFlushMs 0
ModPagespeedDomain https://www.example.com
ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "https://www.example.com/assets/" "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/assets/"
ModPagespeedFileCacheInodeLimit       0
ModPagespeedMaxSegmentLength 1024
```

**UPDATE 2:**
As I was suspecting HTTPS settings prevent it from working, I disabled HTTPS but still nothing combines/rewrites. (I tried to process https resource over http to check, but got the warning: *The preceding resource was not rewritten because its domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) is not authorized*)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is nginx reverse proxy  configuration of the server, which is default in plesk. This requires to install pagespeed for nginx, not apache. Follow the instructions on the documentation [here](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source)